# How to do INNER JOIN with 2 Column COUNTS equal

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am trying to perform the following query:

```
SELECT wwpqsr.statistic_ref_id, 
       wwpqsr.create_time, 
       wwpqm.name
  FROM wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref AS wwpqsr
         INNER JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic AS wwpqs 
           ON (  wwpqs.statistic_ref_id = wwpqsr.statistic_ref_id 
               AND COUNT(wwpqs.correct_count) AS correct = 
                   COUNT(wwpqs.incorrect_count) AS incorrect)
         INNER JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_master AS wwpqm 
           ON (wwpqm.id = wwpqsr.quiz_id)
    WHERE wwpqsr.user_id = 1;
```

I need to do a limit on the result here at the end, that is not being shown right now for functionality purposes, since I need to only get results returned from the `p_wp_pro_quiz_statistic` table where the count of `correct_count` equals the count of rows from the `incorrect_count` column.  How can I do this within an INNER JOIN here?  All within 1 query?  Possible?  The above code returns empty result, where it should not be an empty result.  How should something like this be done?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jorge :)  I knew there had to be a better way to display this.

Comment: I'm surprised that it even worked. You can't use aggregate function on the where clause.

Comment: The count for that two column is based on that three columns?

Comment: So, there are 3 columns being compared, in the 2nd Table there.  The 1st column is comparing the value from the first table, the other 2 columns, just need to compare the `COUNT` of those 2 columns to be equal to each other in the same table.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments, you can't use aggregate functions as a where clause unless it is a field from a subquery. For your case I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT wwpqsr.statistic_ref_id, 
       wwpqsr.create_time, 
       wwpqm.name
  FROM wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref AS wwpqsr
         INNER JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic AS wwpqs 
           ON (  wwpqs.statistic_ref_id = wwpqsr.statistic_ref_id )
         INNER JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_master AS wwpqm 
           ON (wwpqm.id = wwpqsr.quiz_id)
    WHERE wwpqsr.user_id = 1
    GROUP 
       BY wwpqsr.statistic_ref_id, 
          wwpqsr.create_time, 
          wwpqm.name
    HAVING COUNT(wwpqs.correct_count) = COUNT(wwpqs.incorrect_count);
```

Comment: OMG, thank you VERY MUCH.  That is exactly what I needed.  I was looking at the `HAVING` also, just not sure on how to use it.  Thanks so much for that example!!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Comment: I am now experiencing a problem with some rows being returned twice with different `statistic_ref_id` values.  How can I do a `DISTINCT` on just the name here using this query?  I tried `DISTINCT(wwpqm.name)`, but that was not helpful.

Comment: For some reason, `quiz_id` is being returning twice here.  And is returning 3 results, when it should be returning 2.

Comment: To help you you with that I would need to see a sample of your data. Can you set up a small sample of it and what would be the result you desire? Add it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) I would be glad to help!

Comment: Thanks again, solved the issue by simply removing your `GROUP BY` values and changing the value to group by `wwwpqm.name`.  Problem solved.  You're the BEST Bro!

Comment: That's great!! I'm glad that you could solve your problem!!